# Tips on keeping window screen in window sill

Tags: windows

We like to open our windows when it is nice out. Unfortunately the bottom part of our window, where the screen fits into, is not very high. So what happens is our cat tends to push the screen out slightly so he can get out through the bottom by pushing the screen out. The screen does not come out per se but the entire frame is pushed out by our cat. I thought about using duct tape, but that is ugly. The lip is just too small to hold the screen in properly. Wedging a piece of wood in there did not work either.

Thoughts?

Comment: What kind of windows?  A photo might be useful too.

Comment: Single Hung, Bronze Aluminum, 4044 window. I'll see if I can get pictures up tomorrow or Sunday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how the screen fits into the window, I'm not sure that this will work, but here's what I did (I had exactly the same problem - the cats learned that they could get out by pushing against the screens.)

In my case, the screens had an aluminum frame - I took a few small finishing nails, and gently hammered then through the frame, into the channel in the window frame.  I made sure that there was a bit of play in the nail so that they could be pulled out in an emergency (some of the windows were in bedrooms).

Comment: hmm, looked at that today and it does not appear that is a possibility. The lip is too small to nail into. Any other tips? Wife says no on Duct Tape.

Comment: Well, you might be able to find some sort of putty you could use between the screen & the frame - glaziers putty comes to mind, but you could also try a bead of silicon.  You'd want something flexible that doesn't harden, so that you could push the screen out in an emergency.